# Couchbase connection issue with PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, couchbase, nosql

I have a Couchbase CE installation on a VM Debian (ALPHA) and PHP-FPM with NGINX in another VM (BETA).

When i hit Couchbase from PHP it seemed that the Couchbase PHP driver did not even send a request to Couchbase **exactly 1 on 4 tries**!!!

When i restarted the VM that has the Couchbase and tried again it was not responding **exactly 1 on 2 tries**!

When i restarted the **PHP-FPM** of (BETA) VM then suddenly everything worked fine.

Does anybody know why i needed to restart the PHP-FPM on (BETA)?

The even more weird thing is that i have a third PHP-FPM & NGINX VM (GAMMA) that hit the Couchbase on (ALPHA) and it worked normaly all the time without ever needed to restart neither (ALPHA) nor (GAMMA)!

**Versions**

Couchbase Server: Community Edition V4.0

Libcouchbase: 2.5.8

php-couchbase: 2.1

Comment: could you specify versions of couchbase extension, libcouchbase and couchbase server?

Comment: hello thanks for your interest:
Couchbase Server: Communiti Edition Version 4.0
Libcouchbase: 2.5.3
php-couchbase: 2.0.7 (saw it on phpinfo())

Comment: sorry for libcouchbase: 2.5.8 & php-couchbase 2.1